# Move Folders to archived/ backup location with robocopy from a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, windows, stored-procedures

We have a number of folders hundreds of thousand, which relate to items in a database. eg Houses. When a house has been sold over 5 months i have a sql job running to archive the house but on doing so I need to move the related folder to an archived folder. I can get the list of houseid's and write a while loop but its the calling of robocopy and the correct command arguments i need but still have an error log. i understand i will have to fire a new robocopy instance per house id in the loop.

example:
Uploads/House10001 then a user archives the house id 10001 so i need to move the folder to
UploadsArchive/House10001.

How can i achieve the robocopy part and write to an error log.

while archivehouses > 0

id = house id to archive

the bit i need help with is here robocopy ...

end while

Thanks all for your help. If there is a better alternative i am open to suggestions. I have to do this for lots of projects not just one like in the example above.

Comment: Anyone even got any suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First I would suggest NOT to run this from a SP. The reason is you would use SQL Server stack space instead of a seperate process and would require SQL Server Service Account to have access to your network share. You should create a BATCH file or a package to do this.

You need to call SQL to get the list of folders to MOVE with something like:

```
BCP "Stored Procedure" queryout FolderList.txt -S (local) -T -c
```

"Stored Procedure" would return the fullpath folder name of every folders you want to move.
You can use ROBOCOPY or MOVE in a FOR loop like this:

```
FOR /f  %%a IN (FolderList.txt) DO (
    MOVE %%a \\destination\folder
)
```